# How to bind a picker from array in rxswift?

Tags: arrays, rx-swift

I want to bind a picker from an array. The array contains values. But the picker is showing blank.

In view model i took a function in the protocol `func updatedPharmacyList() -> Observable<[String]>`

append the data into an array. 
`self.newArray.append((pharmacy?.name)!)`

the array contains the data.

```
func updatedPharmacyList() -> Observable<[String]> {
    return Observable.just(self.newArray)
}
```

and then in the viewcontroller bind the picker like this

```
viewModel.updatedPharmacyList()
  .bind(to: pharmacyPicker.rx.itemTitles) { _, item in
    return item
  }
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

but the picker is coming blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code should work, check if your observable is working or not by using subscribe method.

```
viewModel.updatedPharmacyList().subscribe {print($0.element)}
```

But if its not working then you can use adapter even you can add or change sections of the picker.

```
let adaptor = RxPickerViewStringAdapter<[String]>( components: [],
                                                       numberOfComponents: { _,_,_  in 2 },
                                                       numberOfRowsInComponent: { (_, _, _, component) -> Int in
                                                        return (component == 0) ? self.model?.arrayForFirst.value.count ?? 0 : self.model?.arrayForSecond.value.count ?? 0 },
                                                       titleForRow: { (_, _, items, row, component) -> String? in
                                                        return (component == 0) ? self.model?.arrayForFirst.value[row] : self.model?.arrayForSecond.value[row]}
    )
model?.arrayForFirst.asObservable()
        .bind(to: self.pickerViewPS.rx.items(adapter: adaptor)).disposed(by: self.bag)
```

For this you have to import RxDataSources.

Comment: how by checking with subscribe or with adapter

Comment: by subscriber sir

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.just(self.newArray)` emits the array as it is at that moment and then emits a completed event. Adding something to the array after that will not be noticed.

The best solution would be to bind the results of whatever is producing the pharmacy list. A "partially Rx" solution would be to replace `newArray` with one of the subject types (probably a `BehaviorRelay` and bind from that to the pharmacyPicker.) Then when you `accept` a new array into the behavior relay, it will notify the picker of the change.

Comment: Okay sir noted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rx picker accepts array of arrays as data, i.e. you need `Observable<[[String]]>`